# Grails CORS not enabled because no origin

Tags: grails, groovy, cors

I have a grails 2.2.4 application. I wanted to enable CORS
So I installed cors plugin by having the following line in build config.

```
plugins {
    runtime ':cors:1.1.8'
}
```

Then in the config.groovy

```
cors.headers = ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*']
```

But after this when I run the application, CORS in not enabled. So I debugged the CORS plugin. The issue seems to be in CorsFilter class in the following method

```
private boolean checkOrigin(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
    if (origin == null) {
        //no origin; per W3C spec, terminate further processing for both preflight and actual requests
        return false;
    }
```

The origin parameter in the above line is always null as the request does not have the parameter 'Origin'. Is there something i'm doing wrong? I'm not looking for the answer which says add a manual header with the name "Origin" since that is not exactly a proper fix

I'm quite new to CORS so appriciate the help.

Comment: There's something wrong in your setup. If https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin is to be believed (and it probably should), every CORS request should include the "Origin" HTTP header. What's generating the request in your test scenario ?

Comment: For testing i'm using RestClient to send the request where in the header I set the content-type and send a GET request to my localhost & Dev server. Using the same RestClient if I send a request to the server where manually I change the CORS setting in Apache cors.conf to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin': *` I get the header back in the response with all origins enabled.  (Since I have load balancing, the new spinned up server gets the default value and anyway i want to handle this by the plugin)

Comment: It doesn't look like RestClient acts as a browser in this case: I can't find in its code anything that hints at it adding an "Origin" header to any request by itself. As you can see in the mozilla link above, a real browser would do it. So it looks like the answer you need is the one you explicitly said you're not looking for... At least, you should only need to do it once by calling `setHeaders([Origin: 'http://idontthinkitmatters/'])` on your RestClient instance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and in addition to setting the Origin header on request, you probably need to specify these response headers as well:

- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
- Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET
- Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST

Also make sure you respond to HTTP OPTIONS requests with these headers and a blank 200 OK response.

Comment: I tried with the following and still I have the same issue. ` "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true"` Maybe sensei's comment is correct that the only solution is adding a header with origin.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers & Access-Control-Allow-Origin has the value *, i'm unable to add them directly as a comment inside "

Comment: A wildcard ought to work for the origin, but a comma separated list won't work for Access-Control-Allow-Methods, I believe you need to repeat the header. With Access-Control-Allow-Headers you need to specify the headers, I don't think a wildcard will work.

Answer (score 0):

For now, let's assume that RestClient is sending the Origin header properly. It may still be getting stripped by your application. You can prevent this using the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin` header.

Most of the problems I have had with my web services is that the right headers are being sent, but they are stripped from the message by my web server. So I tend to adopt a shotgun approach of "allow everything" and then one by one remove what I don't need. My allow-headers header usually is pretty long and I end up having to include stuff like `Content-Type, X-Requested-With` and other junk before my requests will finally go through.

I further recommend that you test using something besides RestClient, if only as a sanity check. I use Postman, a free Chrome app, for all my messaging tests. It looks to me like the problem is with RestClient not sending the proper Origin header.

Comment: I tried with the following and still I have the same issue. ` "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true"` Maybe sensei's comment is correct that the only solution is adding a header with origin. FYI: I tried chrome postman as well, it makes no difference.

Comment: It looks like some of the headers you posted just now in your comment are blank. They don't do any good unless they have values in them. For example the one I pointed out already, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, is blank in what you just tried. If it's blank that means it may be rejecting some headers including Origin.

Comment: Sorry, they have the value * but for some reason it's not being added as a comment.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the * only works for Allow-Origin. I think for the headers and methods you have to specifically list each one you want to allow. At the very least, try listing Origin specifically in Allow-Headers and see if that changes anything. If you still can't get it to work, it might be worth adding the Origin header itself, not as a permanent solution, but just to verify that it does fix the problem. If it doesn't fix the problem, that would indicate a different issue.